# Is there an R function that allows one to compile descriptive statistics (e.g. median, IQR) across multiple columns of data into a single table?

Tags: r, statistics, summary

I'm totally new to R and I'm trying to analyze some healthcare data. I have a dataframe containing multiple different types of prices for a given medical procedure, of which there are 6 versions (231-236). The different prices are the Medicare price, chargemaster price, self-pay price, and commercial price. So there are 6x4=24 columns of data containing prices. Each row represents a different hospital. Is there a way to efficiently collect the medians and IQRs for each of the 24 columns and put them into a table?

So far, I'm just using the summary function: summary(cabg$chargemaster_231) but its very tedious to manually copy and paste the output values into a table. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Using the built-in `mtcars` dataset, something like `sapply(mtcars, \(x) c(median(x), IQR(x)) )` ?

Comment: Try `skimr::skim(yourdataframe)`

Comment: Thank you both! The skim function is really neat - a really basic follow-up question: how do I output the results of the skim command to a new dataframe? As for the sapply() function, I get an error because I have NAs in my data, is there a simple way to bypass this? Thanks so much for your help!